# "$.extend is not a function" while using jquery.easing in nuxt.js

Tags: jquery, vue.js, nuxt.js, jquery-easing

I made an app in Vue.js that I'm trying to adapt in Nuxt.js.
For the scrollspy I used `jquery.easing` in Vue.js so I wanted to do the same in Nuxt.js.

A little like you import jQuery in Vue.js `main.js` file, I created a plugin in Nuxt to add jQuery and `require("jquery.easing")`:

**plugin/jqueryeasing.js**

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import jquery from "jquery";

require("jquery.easing");

Vue.prototype.jquery = jquery;
```

I also linked it to my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   */
  head: {
    title: "resume",
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      { hid: "description", name: "description", content: "undermaintenance" }
    ],

    link: [
      { rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" },

  css: [
    // this line include bootstrap.css in each html file on generate
    "~/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    // main css file in document
    "assets/css/main.css"
  ],

  /*
   ** Plugin section
   */
  plugins: [
    "~plugins/bootstrap.js"
    "~plugins/jqueryeasing.js",
  ],

  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {
    /**
     * add external plugins
     */
    vendor: ["jquery", "bootstrap"],
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery"
      })
    ],
    /*
     ** Run ESLint on save
     */
    extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: "pre",
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: "eslint-loader",
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
```

jQuery is working like a charm with my Bootstrap.

I don't know why but I'm having this

> typeError: $.extend is not a function.

It comes from my `node_modules/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.js` file.

```js
$.extend($.easing, {
  def: "easeOutQuad",
  swing: function(x) {
    return $.easing[$.easing.def](x);
  },
  easeInQuad: function(x) {
```

Version information:

```
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"jquery.easing": "^1.4.1"
```

I've tried to:

- Use an extended version of jQuery
- Add jQuery UI: `"jquery-ui": "^1.12.1"`,
- Use CDN and script in `nuxt.config.js` file only
- Use an older version of jQuery and `jQuery.easing`

What am I doing wrong and how come it works in Vue.js?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jquery-easing the simple way is to add it like this :

```
 1- Inside your nuxt.config.js
  script: [
  {
    src:
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js'
  }     
]
```

Answer (score 0):

J-query and Nuxt.js are not best friends.

I used a plugin called vuetifyjs. You will find a scroll `goTo` function where you can fix options including smooth scrolling (using built-in easing functions), duration and offset.

This is the link to the documentation:
https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/scroll

Comment: vuetify i not a simple plugin, it is a display framework like qasar or bootstrap, if you have bootstrap and need jquery you will not install vuetify only to make work one thing in js